# Apple store update?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have an app in apple store, I want to update it. But instead of working on old project, I created a new project and now it is finished. If I upload the new one, does apple reject it because of different sku and appids. Older version was very bad and I created totally new app. What should I do to update  my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make sure:

- your application identifier is the same
- you sign it with the same developer certificate/identity
- new version > old version

Comment: I bought a new mac, so signing with the same dev certificate is impossible because I created a diff certificate on new mac. And if I change app identifier, app crashes on simulator.

Comment: You should regenerate the key and create a new certificate, but still use same apple dev account. Sorry I was not very specific.

Comment: the new certificate I created belongs to my dev acc. The older certificate belonged to the same acc, too. Do I need to create a new one?

Comment: You do not need to use the same certificate nor identity. Just need to use the same developer account.

Answer (score 4):

In your apps Info.plist, you want to make sure that the Bundle Identifier between the two apps match, and that the new app has a higher version than the old app. Then you should be able to successfully submit your new version to Apple.

Comment: If I change bundle identifier, app crashes on simulator. Is it because developer certificate belongs to a different app id ?

Comment: Try cleaning your app. CMD + Shift + k. Worst case delete the old version from the simulator.